# Seeking birthplace of William Kruse, b 1899

Tags: germany, birth-records, 1890s

Seeking birth place of William Kruse, Father, born 1899, Hanover Area, served in the Imperial Army in WW1, and was wounded in mustard gas attack.

The Kruse family owned a large farm in Hanover area that was taken over by Hitler's forces

Comment: What do you got on him? (Documents) His name was surely *Wilhelm*.